# STIntersection returning NULL with seemingly valid geography data

Tags: sql-server

I want to include only the portion of Alaska that's in the western hemisphere. Apparently, some islands are on the other side of the international dateline. I am using `STIntersection` to intersect the shapefile data I have for Alaska (stored in a geography column) and a text-specified polygon that includes only the western hemisphere. However, `STIntersection` is returning NULL. The documentation says that it will return NULL if the SRIDs don't match. I checked the SRIDs of both the shape data for Alaska and the text-specified polygon, and they both say 4326, as expected. I'm not sure what to do now. My guess is that I'm not specifying the polygon properly, though it does show up the Spatial Results tab just fine.

This is the SQL to generate the western hemisphere polygon:

```
SELECT geography::STPolyFromText('POLYGON((-180 0, -1 0, -1 90, -180 0))', 4326) AS s
```

This appears in the spatial results window as this:

[image: Western hemisphere shape]

This is the SQL for Alaska. I have a table of shapefile data (from the US census bureau), which I can't easily reproduce here, so you'll have to take my word for it.

```
SELECT shape
  FROM shapefile_state
 WHERE enum_state = 2
```

The spatial results window shows this:

[image: Alaska shape]

If I do a union of those two shapes,

```
SELECT geography::STPolyFromText('POLYGON((-180 0, -1 0, -1 90, -180 0))', 4326) AS s
UNION ALL
SELECT shape
  FROM shapefile_state
 WHERE enum_state = 2
```

I get this:

[image: Combined shapes]

That implies that the polygon should be overlapping Alaska (specifically, the parts in the western hemisphere). And yet the NULL result from the following query:

```
SELECT geography::STPolyFromText('POLYGON((-180 0, -1 0, -1 90, -180 0))', 4326).STIntersection(shape)
 FROM shapefile_state
 WHERE enum_state = 2
```

Sanity check:

```
SELECT shape.STSrid, geography::STPolyFromText('POLYGON((-180 0, -1 0, -1 90, -180 0))', 4326).STSrid
 FROM shapefile_state
 WHERE enum_state = 2
```

This returns 4326 for both columns.

My knowledge of spatial data is not deep, so I am not sure how to debug this further.

EDIT: here is the shapefile data for Alaska as outputted by STAsText(): http://pastebin.com/AAf5gMSH.

Comment: Interesting problem - I can reproduce it using an Alaska shapefile (started as geometry but converted to geography).  What's weird is that STIntersection is working just fine with geometries.  But the same shapes as geography return NULLs just like you say. I'm not as familiar with geography vs geometry, but am curious how to get this to work!  For what it's worth, `poly.STIntersects(stategeography)` returns true, so it seems to recognize that, just has trouble returning the difference.

Comment: @PeterTirrell Thanks. You know, that might be good enough. I don't need the whole western hemisphere, just the part of it that contains the US, Alaska and Hawaii. Do you know of an easy way to migrate this question to GIS SE without having to simply repost it?

Comment: Is there any way you can provide the shapefile that you're using for Alaska?

Comment: @BenThul: the data is in a table. I could export it as binary to a file, I suppose. It's fairly large.

Comment: @siride: You can reduce the size of the geography object by calling the `Reduce()` method on it with a fairly high tolerance. I'm just looking to get in the ballpark. But before you export the reduced object, make sure that it also exhibits the pathological behavior that we're trying to solve for.

Comment: I used this data: ftp://ftp2.census.gov/geo/tiger/TIGER2010/STATE/2010/tl_2010_02_state10.zip.

Comment: I downloaded the file and loaded it to SQLServer 2014.  I got SRID 4269.  When I ran your query, I got a shape back.  This seems to be working for me.  I did drop the enum_state filter because it doesn't exist in the shape file though.

Comment: @travis: I'm using 2008R2 if that makes any difference. The field type in my database is geography, not geometry (in case that results in a difference), and when it was loaded, it was explicitly set to the given SRID (4326).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First some associations. From the [postgis docs](https://postgis.net/docs/manual-2.2/using_postgis_dbmanagement.html#PostGIS_Geography).

geometry <-> plane

geography <-> sphere

Make sure the intersection is calculated using geometry data types. [See the docs on STIntersection](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/spatial-geometry/stintersection-geometry-data-type?view=sql-server-ver15). Convert/Typecast if necessary. Since you only want a simple intersection I don't think you need to reproject. If you want your output in geography you might need to [validate it](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/edkatibah/working-with-invalid-data-and-the-sql-server-2008-geography-data-type-part-1b).

I don't use SQL Server so this might not work.

```
SELECT geography::(geometry::(STPolyFromText('POLYGON((-180 0, -1 0, -1 90, -180 0))', 4326)).STIntersection(geometry::shape))
FROM shapefile_state
WHERE enum_state = 2
```

Comment: This fixed it. I had to adjust the syntax a little bit: `SELECT geography::STGeomFromText(geometry::STPolyFromText('POLYGON((-180 90, 0 90, 0 0, -180 0, -180 90))', 4326).STIntersection(geometry::STGeomFromWKB(shapefile_state.shape.STAsBinary(), shape.STSrid)).STAsText(), shapefile_state.shape.STSrid) AS shape`